# Rfacebook package, "fbOAuth(appid, appsecret)" fails to get an access token. Returns bad request (HTTP 400)

Tags: r, facebook, oauth, rstudio, rfacebook

I am trying to scrape some text from fb using the 'Rfacebook' package.
Even after installing Rfacebook & tm, running relevant libraries (Rfacebook, httr, tm, and httpuv), `fboAuth(appid, appsecret)` is failing to get the reqd. access token. Please see the code and ensuing error below:

```
install.packages("Rfacebook")
install.packages("tm")
library(devtools)
library(Rfacebook)
library(httr)
library(httpuv)
library(tm)

appid <- 123
appsecret <- 'mysecret123'

fboauth <- fbOAuth(appid, appsecret, extended_permissions = T)
```

Which returns 
**Copy and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings:** 
    http://localhost:1410/ 
**When done, press any key to continue**...

Upon pasting the redirect url in the cell [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoHvs.jpg), a browser opened.

And, although the browser displayed "*Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to R.*", an error msg was returned in the RStudio console (attached below.) Again, I tried this with Safari as well as Chrome as default browsers - no change.

**Authentication complete.
Error in init_oauth2.0(self$endpoint, self$app, scope = self$params$scope,  : 
  Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to get an access token.**

Any help in resolving this is truly appreciated!

Best,

S

**p.s.** Using R-Studio v3.3.2 on a Mac (OS Sierra.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following
a) remove httr package
b) remove RCurl package
c) remove RFacebook
d) Reinstall httr , then RCurl, and then RFacebook
e) get the latest version of R studio
f) After you authenticate, and when you get the message  Copy and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings: http://localhost:1410/ When done, press any key to continue... 
You may want to do save(user_fbOauth) where user_fbOauth are your credentials
g) then pass them to any other request

I have tried this and dont see any issues